# Using java's regex api to insert words be

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to regular expressions and java so please bear with my newbish question.

I want to do the following:

If I have a string:

```
"I like ice cream only if it is chocolate ice cream. Chocolate cream"
```

and a pattern like

```
"chocolate ice cream"
```

I want to match and replace all words matched with a # surrounding them. Like this:

```
"I like #ice cream# only if it is #chocolate ice cream#. #Cholcolate cream#"
```

I used java's regex api and I understand I can use `Matcher.replaceAll`. But I'm having trouble coming up with a proper regex. I came up with this `chocolate*\\s*ice*\\s*cream*`. But the problem here is it's only matching the whole substring, i.e `"chocolate ice cream"`. I think something like this could work:

```
chocolate|ice|cream|chocolate ice|ice cream|chocolate cream|chocolate ice cream
```

etc, i.e all permutations, but this would be cumbersome as the substring grows.

I would appreciate any ideas on proceeding in the right direction.

Comment: Does order matter? Do you want `ice chocolate` to match?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the pattern:

```
(?i)\b((?:chocolate|ice|cream)(?:\s+(?:chocolate|ice|cream))*)\b
```

and replace it with:

```
#$1#
```

Demo:

```
String s = "I like ice cream only if it is chocolate ice cream. Chocolate cream";
s = s.replaceAll("(?i)\\b((?:chocolate|ice|cream)(?:\\s+(?:chocolate|ice|cream))*)\\b", "#$1#");
System.out.println(s);
```

The word boundaries cause "creamy" (and other such words) *not* to be replaced.

Note that this will change `"ice ice"` into `"#ice ice#"` (ie. the words can occur more than once!), as @stema mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Nice pattern if it is OK to match stuff like `cream ice cream`

Answer (score 3):

```
(?:chocolate|ice|cream)(?:\s+(?:chocolate|ice|cream))*
```

This will match one or more of the specified words delimited by whitespace

Comment: And maybe make it case insensitive to have the exact output as mentioned in the question `(?i:chocolate|ice|cream)(?i:\\s+(?:chocolate|ice|cream))*`

Comment: Note that `"ice creamy"` will now be changed into: `"#ice cream#y"`. Perhaps that is what the OP wants, but perhaps not.

Comment: @Bart true, +1 to your solution for catching that :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final String source = "I like ice cream only if it is chocolate ice cream. Chocolate cream";
final String result = source.replaceAll("((?:[Cc]hocolate )?(?:[Ii]ce )?cream)", "#$1#");

// Prints I like #ice cream# only if it is #chocolate ice cream#. #Chocolate cream#
System.out.println(result);
```

See [Optional Items](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will find interesting MessageFormat from the Java API

```
Object[] testArgs = {new Long(3), "MyDisk"};

MessageFormat form = new MessageFormat(
  "The disk \"{1}\" contains {0} file(s).");

 System.out.println(form.format(testArgs));

 // output, with different testArgs
 output: The disk "MyDisk" contains 0 file(s).
 output: The disk "MyDisk" contains 1 file(s).
 output: The disk "MyDisk" contains 1,273 file(s).
```